# Jetty websocket client: Not Valid UTF8

Tags: apache, websocket, tomcat7, jetty-9

Any advice on how to fix this problem would be much appreciated.

I am using the jetty websocket (9.2.6.v20141205) client to connect via apache2 proxy_wstunnel to tomcat7 websocket server.

I get the following error intermittently:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable$NotUtf8Exception: Not valid UTF8! byte 88 in state 0
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.appendByte(Utf8Appendable.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8Appendable.append(Utf8Appendable.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8LineParser.parseByte(Utf8LineParser.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8LineParser.parseByte(Utf8LineParser.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Utf8LineParser.parse(Utf8LineParser.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.http.HttpResponseHeaderParser.parse(HttpResponseHeaderParser.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.read(UpgradeConnection.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.onFillable(UpgradeConnection.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:546)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I remove the apache2 proxy_wstunnel then the error goes away. I've also noticed in the ngrep logs that apache is giving a 500 error, but even if I turn on LogLevel debug I don't see relevant logs. This has consumed several hours of my time. There is also no errors in the tomcat logs.

I do want to continue using wstunnel. Perhaps this is a jetty bug or apache bug?

Here is the ngrep logs:

```
    filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 80 )
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [S]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AS]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /trandomain-
      73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
      0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77    73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    .Host: ws.domain
      2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    .io..Upgrade: we
      62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    bsocket..Connect
      69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    ion: Upgrade..Se
      63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79 3a    c-WebSocket-Key:
      20 56 50 54 4a 79 42 6b    30 36 38 65 7a 66 30 62     VPTJyBk068ezf0b
      34 57 66 41 39 73 51 3d    3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d 57    4WfA9sQ==..Sec-W
      65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74    2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e    ebSocket-Version
      3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50 72    61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f    : 13..Pragma: no
      2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a    43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f    -cache..Cache-Co
      6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ntrol: no-cache.
      0a 0d 0a                                              ...             
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AP]
      48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31    20 31 30 31 20 53 77 69    HTTP/1.1 101 Swi
      74 63 68 69 6e 67 20 50    72 6f 74 6f 63 6f 6c 73    tching Protocols
      0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72    3a 20 41 70 61 63 68 65    ..Server: Apache
      2d 43 6f 79 6f 74 65 2f    31 2e 31 0d 0a 55 70 67    -Coyote/1.1..Upg
      72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    rade: websocket.
      0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    69 6f 6e 3a 20 75 70 67    .Connection: upg
      72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    rade..Sec-WebSoc
      6b 65 74 2d 41 63 63 65    70 74 3a 20 31 4a 51 76    ket-Accept: 1JQv
      41 2f 43 56 55 5a 38 59    6d 4d 4a 38 70 62 33 53    A/CVUZ8YmMJ8pb3S
      48 33 51 47 56 4e 34 3d    0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20    H3QGVN4=..Date: 
      57 65 64 2c 20 32 34 20    44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34    Wed, 24 Dec 2014
      20 31 34 3a 33 31 3a 31    37 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 0d     14:31:17 GMT...
      0a                                                    .               
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      82 9c ea 9e d0 54 e2 9e    c3 1e eb af c4 47 a0 98    .....T.......G..
      a4 31 99 ea e1 61 fe 8d    9a 53 9e fb a3 20 db ac    .1...a...S... ..
      e3 40                                                 .@              
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AP]
      82 09                                                 ..              
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AP]
      08 00 13 4a 03 32 37 30    14                         ...J.270.       
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P`.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P`.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P`.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P`.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [S]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AS]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /trandomain-
      73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
      0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77    73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    .Host: ws.domain
      2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    .io..Upgrade: we
      62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    bsocket..Connect
      69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    ion: Upgrade..Se
      63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79 3a    c-WebSocket-Key:
      20 53 35 65 55 79 36 78    6a 55 53 70 51 46 57 47     S5eUy6xjUSpQFWG
      37 2b 4a 4d 66 2b 51 3d    3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d 57    7+JMf+Q==..Sec-W
      65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74    2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e    ebSocket-Version
      3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50 72    61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f    : 13..Pragma: no
      2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a    43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f    -cache..Cache-Co
      6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ntrol: no-cache.
      0a 0d 0a                                              ...             
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AP]
      48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31    20 31 30 31 20 53 77 69    HTTP/1.1 101 Swi
      74 63 68 69 6e 67 20 50    72 6f 74 6f 63 6f 6c 73    tching Protocols
      0d 0a 53 65 72 76 65 72    3a 20 41 70 61 63 68 65    ..Server: Apache
      2d 43 6f 79 6f 74 65 2f    31 2e 31 0d 0a 55 70 67    -Coyote/1.1..Upg
      72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    rade: websocket.
      0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    69 6f 6e 3a 20 75 70 67    .Connection: upg
      72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    rade..Sec-WebSoc
      6b 65 74 2d 41 63 63 65    70 74 3a 20 52 56 43 4b    ket-Accept: RVCK
      72 41 6c 7a 59 30 66 4b    38 38 61 4d 43 30 61 37    rAlzY0fK88aMC0a7
      6e 31 74 62 35 71 38 3d    0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20    n1tb5q8=..Date: 
      57 65 64 2c 20 32 34 20    44 65 63 20 32 30 31 34    Wed, 24 Dec 2014
      20 31 34 3a 33 31 3a 33    39 20 47 4d 54 0d 0a 0d     14:31:39 GMT...
      0a                                                    .               
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      82 9c a1 86 a8 97 a9 86    bb dd a0 b7 bc 84 eb 80    ................
      dc f2 d2 f2 99 a2 b5 95    e2 90 d5 e3 db e3 90 b4    ................
      9b 83                                                 ..              
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AP]
      82 09                                                 ..              
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AP]
      08 00 13 4a 03 32 37 30    14                         ...J.270.       
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P`.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a bc 23 03 08 bf ca    50 60 c9 57 67 67 cb 4d    ...#....P`.Wgg.M
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [S]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AS]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49975 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AP]
      47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /trandomain-
      73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
      0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 77    73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    .Host: ws.domain
      2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 3a 20 77 65    .io..Upgrade: we
      62 73 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    bsocket..Connect
      69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    72 61 64 65 0d 0a 53 65    ion: Upgrade..Se
      63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f 63    6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79 3a    c-WebSocket-Key:
      20 62 45 54 54 44 72 77    54 75 69 64 4f 67 4a 4a     bETTDrwTuidOgJJ
      68 73 56 7a 31 4c 41 3d    3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d 57    hsVz1LA==..Sec-W
      65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74    2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e    ebSocket-Version
      3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50 72    61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e 6f    : 13..Pragma: no
      2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d 0a    43 61 63 68 65 2d 43 6f    -cache..Cache-Co
      6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ntrol: no-cache.
      0a 0d 0a                                              ...             
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AP]
      88 0a 03 e9 53 68 75 74    64 6f 77 6e                ....Shutdown    
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AP]
      3c 21 44 4f 43 54 59 50    45 20 48 54 4d 4c 20 50    ..
      3c 74 69 74 6c 65 3e 35    30 30 20 49 6e 74 65 72    500 Inter
      6e 61 6c 20 53 65 72 76    65 72 20 45 72 72 6f 72    nal Server Error
      3c 2f 74 69 74 6c 65 3e    0a 3c 2f 68 65 61 64 3e    .
      3c 62 6f 64 79 3e 0a 3c    68 31 3e 49 6e 74 65 72    .Inter
      6e 61 6c 20 53 65 72 76    65 72 20 45 72 72 6f 72    nal Server Error
      3c 2f 68 31 3e 0a 3c 70    3e 54 68 65 20 73 65 72    .The ser
      76 65 72 20 65 6e 63 6f    75 6e 74 65 72 65 64 20    ver encountered 
      61 6e 20 69 6e 74 65 72    6e 61 6c 20 65 72 72 6f    an internal erro
      72 20 6f 72 0a 6d 69 73    63 6f 6e 66 69 67 75 72    r or.misconfigur
      61 74 69 6f 6e 20 61 6e    64 20 77 61 73 20 75 6e    ation and was un
      61 62 6c 65 20 74 6f 20    63 6f 6d 70 6c 65 74 65    able to complete
      0a 79 6f 75 72 20 72 65    71 75 65 73 74 2e 3c 2f    .your request..Please con
      74 61 63 74 20 74 68 65    20 73 65 72 76 65 72 20    tact the server 
      61 64 6d 69 6e 69 73 74    72 61 74 6f 72 20 61 74    administrator at
      20 0a 20 77 65 62 6d 61    73 74 65 72 40 6c 6f 63     . webmaster@loc
      61 6c 68 6f 73 74 20 74    6f 20 69 6e 66 6f 72 6d    alhost to inform
      20 74 68 65 6d 20 6f 66    20 74 68 65 20 74 69 6d     them of the tim
      65 20 74 68 69 73 20 65    72 72 6f 72 20 6f 63 63    e this error occ
      75 72 72 65 64 2c 0a 20    61 6e 64 20 74 68 65 20    urred,. and the 
      61 63 74 69 6f 6e 73 20    79 6f 75 20 70 65 72 66    actions you perf
      6f 72 6d 65 64 20 6a 75    73 74 20 62 65 66 6f 72    ormed just befor
      65 20 74 68 69 73 20 65    72 72 6f 72 2e 3c 2f 70    e this error..More inform
      61 74 69 6f 6e 20 61 62    6f 75 74 20 74 68 69 73    ation about this
      20 65 72 72 6f 72 20 6d    61 79 20 62 65 20 61 76     error may be av
      61 69 6c 61 62 6c 65 0a    69 6e 20 74 68 65 20 73    ailable.in the s
      65 72 76 65 72 20 65 72    72 6f 72 20 6c 6f 67 2e    erver error log.
      3c 2f 70 3e 0a 3c 68 72    3e 0a 3c 61 64 64 72 65    ..Apache/2.4.7 
      28 55 62 75 6e 74 75 29    20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20    (Ubuntu) Server 
      61 74 20 77 73 2e 73 6c    61 74 6f 72 2e 69 6f 20    at ws.domain.io 
      50 6f 72 74 20 38 30 3c    2f 61 64 64 72 65 73 73    Port 80.
      0a                                                    .               
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [A]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49975 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AR]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AFP]
      88 8a ad d9 9f c4 ae 30    cc ac d8 ad fb ab da b7    .......0........
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49983 [AF]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49983 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AR]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 105.210.y.y:49991 -> 104.131.x.x:80 [AF]
      00 00 00 00 00 00                                     ......          
    #
    T 104.131.x.x:80 -> 105.210.y.y:49991 [A]
    exit
    83 received, 0 dropped
```

Here is the ngrep logs between apache and tomcat:

```
interface: lo (127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0)
filter: (ip or ip6) and ( port 8080 )
#
T 127.0.0.1:57952 -> 127.0.0.1:8080 [AP]
  47 45 54 20 2f 74 72 61    6e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2d    GET /translator-
  73 72 76 2f 77 73 20 48    54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d    srv/ws HTTP/1.1.
  0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 6c    6f 63 61 6c 68 6f 73 74    .Host: localhost
  3a 38 30 38 30 0d 0a 53    65 63 2d 57 65 62 53 6f    :8080..Sec-WebSo
  63 6b 65 74 2d 4b 65 79    3a 20 64 36 57 73 6c 6b    cket-Key: d6Wslk
  56 48 77 79 4d 47 77 62    5a 4f 6c 71 56 53 2b 51    VHwyMGwbZOlqVS+Q
  3d 3d 0d 0a 53 65 63 2d    57 65 62 53 6f 63 6b 65    ==..Sec-WebSocke
  74 2d 56 65 72 73 69 6f    6e 3a 20 31 33 0d 0a 50    t-Version: 13..P
  72 61 67 6d 61 3a 20 6e    6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65 0d    ragma: no-cache.
  0a 43 61 63 68 65 2d 43    6f 6e 74 72 6f 6c 3a 20    .Cache-Control: 
  6e 6f 2d 63 61 63 68 65    0d 0a 58 2d 46 6f 72 77    no-cache..X-Forw
  61 72 64 65 64 2d 46 6f    72 3a 20 31 30 35 2e 32    arded-For: 105.2
  31 30 2e 33 38 2e 31 34    39 0d 0a 58 2d 46 6f 72    10.38.149..X-For
  77 61 72 64 65 64 2d 48    6f 73 74 3a 20 77 73 2e    warded-Host: ws.
  73 6c 61 74 6f 72 2e 69    6f 0d 0a 58 2d 46 6f 72    slator.io..X-For
  77 61 72 64 65 64 2d 53    65 72 76 65 72 3a 20 77    warded-Server: w
  73 2e 73 6c 61 74 6f 72    2e 69 6f 0d 0a 55 70 67    s.slator.io..Upg
  72 61 64 65 3a 20 57 65    62 53 6f 63 6b 65 74 0d    rade: WebSocket.
  0a 43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74    69 6f 6e 3a 20 55 70 67    .Connection: Upg
  72 61 64 65 0d 0a 0d 0a                               rade....        
#
T 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 127.0.0.1:57952 [R]
exit
4 received, 0 dropped
```

Comment: Might want to include the Apache <-> Jetty layer ngrep too.  As it appears all of the upgrades are being done by Apache itself.

Comment: Why are you running tomcat and jetty? Pick one or the other? it will make life so much easier.

Comment: Will attach the traffic between apache and tomcat shortly

Comment: @joakim, is embedding jetty websocket server inside tomcat web server not adding more complexity? Am I missing the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to compile the latest version of apache on my server and that seemed to solve the issue.

I created this question and answer to document that process:

https://serverfault.com/questions/655722/how-do-i-compile-the-latest-apache2-on-ubuntu-using-the-original-layout-configu/655724#655724